# How do I maintain a newly laid oiled floor?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, maintenance

I just bought an Emperor Oak Oiled Floor. The salesman of the reseller said it has been oiled 7 times with Woca oil but advises another coat once laid.

Reading forums, opinion seems split:

1. > it's quite common (these days with so many products coming from China)
   >   the "oil" used on pre-finished boards is not really protecting against
   >   drips and spillages.  When we install boards like this, we either
   >   apply a wax-polish or one coat of HardWaxOil to create a better wear
   >   and tear layer.
2. > Why would you want to re-oil a pre-oiled floor straight after
   >   installation??  Use a suitable maintenance product 4 weeks after
   >   installation and then every 5 -6 months.
3. > Don't re-oil - use a proper maintenance product!

So:

- What do you think?
- Which one is best for me?
- Should I be applying another coat of oil once laid?
- Should this be a maintenance oil? Or a normal hardwax oil?
- Should I use a floor soap first like "Osmo Wash and Care"?

Comment: I removed your forum link since it didn't contain any useful information and your post here seems to be more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Any oil-based finish is not very durable and must be renewed periodically. Flooring is usually finished with a polyurethane varnish for this reason (in the old days it would have been an alkyd varnish). It does; however, preserve the look and feel of real wood without having an obvious film finish on top of it.

The installation process can scuff up the surface which is why hardwood floors are finished after they are installed.

The MSDS for Woca oil [(here)](http://www.wocaoil.com/files/84078945.pdf) indicates the presence of a drying agent so it shouldn't be too much trouble to wipe on another coat - it should cure fairly fast.

Comment: That's the usual tradeoff -- oil finishes wear faster but are easier to refresh.